# can I mix. trisodium phosphate, potassium hydroxide, and sodium hydroxide together?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Can I mix trisodium phosphate (tsp), potassium hydroxide, and sodium hydroxide ( or sodium hypochlorite ) and not cause a bad reaction?  And will this make for a good degreaser and cleaning chemical for me ?  I own a pressure washing business.  I do fast food resturanta, gas stations

Comment: You will not cause any bad reaction, as far as I can guess. The trisodium phosphate only gets rid of some of the mineral content of the water making it softer, the hydroxides will definitely make a good deggreasing agent. But I'm not sure, whether you need to mix, isn't e.g. sodium hydroxide in itself enough? You can also use sodium hypochlorite with sodium hydroxide or potassium hydroxide without problems, I'm not sure about using it with tsp., that might lead to chlorine formation. You can always try in a small cup with small quantities, preferably in open air, and see if chlorine forms.

Answer (score 2):

I advise against using potassium or sodium hydroxide in homemade cleaning agents. You could easily end up with a mixture that could severely burn eyes (up to blindness), skin or lungs.

Also, grease from fast food restaurants is fundamentally different from gas station grease. The former consists most probably of [fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat) while the latter is a [mineral oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_oil) product.

Your home-made degreaser, with a hydroxide concentration that could be handled without complete personal protective equipment, might or might not have some effect on fat due to [saponification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saponification) but for removing mineral oil based grease I would not expect it to be effective.

Answer (score -1):

Potassium hydroxide, and sodium hydroxide tend to produce heat when you dissolve them in water, tbs is very peaceful. So if you dump a kilo of NaOH in a bucked of water it might shoot up the ceiling and burn your skin if it splashes on you. If you add it slowly you will be OK. If you want to make a liter of the solution start by adding a table spoon of NaOH and look what happens. You can increase the rate of addition as you get more comfortable. I would personally add 100 g of NaOH to 1 liter in 10 portions over 5 minutes, but that is because I know what I am doing. You will need to stir solution with a right tool (at least don't use your hand or aluminum spoon).

NaOH and KOH dust are nasty. You will need eye protection, gloves,      labcoat and a shower nearby in case of emergency.

This solution will absorb CO2 and lose activity, so you need to seal it.

---

tldr They are not going to blow up but you shouldn't add them too fast to each other.

Comment: Please feel free to leave a comment explaining why you downvote and provide a correct answer.